# Adding trailing and leading zeroes

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do we convert and add trailing and leading zeros to a number? For example 123.45. I need to make this ten digits long and have padding numbers in front and back. I would like to convert it to 0001234500. Two trailing numbers after the last digit of the decimal. Remove the decimal. Fill in the remaining space with zeroes for the leading end.

I have this so far and it adds trailing zeroes and removes the decimal.

```
REPLACE(RIGHT('0'+CAST(rtrim(convert(char(10),convert(decimal(10,4),Field))) AS VARCHAR(10)),10),'.','') as New_Field
```

Comment: Are you really learning MySQL and SQL Server at the same time or you're just unsure of what engine you have?

Comment: tag only the real db you are using please

Comment: I am learning SQl Server. Starting from the begining with W3school and jumping straight into what my uncle calls "real world" queries.

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag, and added the SQL tag as it looks that right now you are using SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: the string concat is diiferent between mysql and sql-server so  you should choose a real  db

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL you would have `RPAD` and `LPAD` to get stuff like this done, in SQL Server (2012+) you can get something similar by working with `FORMAT`.

Easiest way is to FORMAT your numbers with a dot so that they take the right place in the format string, then remove that dot. You need to specify a locale, since in different regions you will get a different decimal sign (even if you use `.` within the format pattern, you would get `,` in various locales) - using `en-US` makes sure you get a dot.

```
REPLACE(FORMAT(somenumber, '000000.0000', 'en-US'), '.', '')
```

A few examples:

```
WITH TempTable(somenumber) AS (
    SELECT 3
    UNION SELECT 3.4 
    UNION SELECT 3.45 
    UNION SELECT 23.45 
    UNION SELECT 123.45
)
SELECT 
    somenumber,
    REPLACE(FORMAT(somenumber, '000000.0000', 'en-US'), '.', '')
FROM 
    TempTable;
```

Gives

```
3.00    0000030000
3.40    0000034000
3.45    0000034500
23.45   0000234500
123.45  0001234500
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to really be overthinking what you need to do here. If we take it in steps, perhaps you'll see that this can be achieved much more easily. This solution runs under the idea that the value `123.45` becomes `0001234500` and `6.5` becomes `0000065000`.

Firstly, let's pad out the right hand side of the number `123.45` so that we have `1234500` That's easy enough : `123. 45 * 100 = 12345` So, to get `1234500` we simply need to multiple it by a couple of extra factors of 10:

```
SELECT 123.45 * 10000; --1234500.00
```

Ok, now, let's get rid of those decimal places. Easiest way, convert it to an `int`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, 123.45 * 10000); --1234500
```

Nice! Now, the finalstep, the leading 0's. A numerical value, in SQL Server, won't display leading zeros. `SELECT 01, 001.00;` Will return `1` and `1.00` respectively. A `varchar` however, will though (as it's not a number). We can, therefore, make use of that with a further conversion, and then then use of `RIGHT`:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000000000' + CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(int,123.45 * 10000)),10);
```

Now you have the value you want `'0001234500'`.

If you're only after padding, (so `6.5` becomes `0006500`) then you should be able to work out how to achieve this with the help above (hint you don't need `RIGHT`).

Any questions, please do ask.

Comment: Hey Larnu, Thanks for your help.  Can you also help with this.  As the number 123.45, I used that as an example.  The numbers that I'll be getting are from a field and lengths and numbers will vary.  Is there a spot where I can call in the number from the field needed?

Comment: @J.Ngo You're welcome. You're had a few answers here, so make sure you make the one that provided you the answer as the solution, and upvote any that helped you get there. :)

Comment: @J.Ngo simply use the **column**'s (not field's) name instead of the literal value. I.e. `SELECT [YourColumn] * 10000;`